# SQL Server Partition by ID and Add or Subtract Preceding Rows Based on Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compute the closing balance of an ID based on the Opening Balance and Event Type

Below is the sample data

| ID | Date_Opened | Opening_Amount | Event_Date | Event_Amount | Event_Remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | Open |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 2/17/2020 | 74,984 | Payment |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 5/4/2020 | 74,984 | Reversal |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 7/19/2021 | 2 | Closed |
| 10 | 9/10/2020 | 250,000 | 9/10/2020 | 250,000 | Open |
| 39 | 5/26/2021 | 117,075 | 5/7/2021 | 117,075 | Open |
| 39 | 5/26/2021 | 117,075 | 7/14/2021 | 45,467 | Payment |
| 39 | 5/26/2021 | 117,075 | 8/17/2021 | 22,083 | Payment |
| 41 | 6/3/2021 | 129,096 | 5/26/2021 | 129,096 | OPen |
| 41 | 6/3/2021 | 129,096 | 8/13/2021 | 122,772 | Payment |
| 48 | 6/30/2021 | 42,350 | 6/25/2021 | 42,350 | Open |
| 48 | 6/30/2021 | 42,350 | 8/3/2021 | 42,196 | Payment |
| 47 | 7/23/2021 | 100,980 | 6/24/2021 | 100,980 | Open |
| 51 | 7/28/2021 | 81,458 | 7/15/2021 | 81,458 | Open |
| 52 | 7/30/2021 | 46,750 | 7/27/2021 | 46,750 | Open |
| 52 | 7/30/2021 | 46,750 | 8/24/2021 | 46,750 | Payment |
| 53 | 8/6/2021 | 45,100 | 8/2/2021 | 45,100 | Open |
| 55 | 8/11/2021 | 43,725 | 8/9/2021 | 43,725 | Open |

The following conditions should be

1. Open - closing balance equals event amount
2. Payment - Subtract event amount from the previous balance
3. Reversal - Add event amount to the previous balance
4. Closed - Closing Balance is 0

Based on these conditions, i want the final output to be as follows

| ID | Date_Opened | Opening_Amount | Event_Date | Event_Amount | Event_Remarks | Closing_Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | Open | 74,986 |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 2/17/2020 | 74,984 | Payment | 2 |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 5/4/2020 | 74,984 | Reversal | 74,986 |
| 13 | 12/31/2019 | 74,986 | 7/19/2021 | 2 | Closed | 0 |
| 39 | 5/26/2021 | 117,075 | 5/7/2021 | 117,075 | Open | 117,075 |
| 39 | 5/26/2021 | 117,075 | 7/14/2021 | 45,467 | Payment | 71,608 |
| 39 | 5/26/2021 | 117,075 | 8/17/2021 | 22,083 | Payment | 49,525 |
| 41 | 6/3/2021 | 129,096 | 5/26/2021 | 129,096 | OPen | 129,096 |
| 41 | 6/3/2021 | 129,096 | 8/13/2021 | 122,772 | Payment | 6,324 |
| 47 | 7/23/2021 | 100,980 | 6/24/2021 | 100,980 | Open | 100,980 |
| 48 | 6/30/2021 | 42,350 | 6/25/2021 | 42,350 | Open | 42,350 |
| 48 | 6/30/2021 | 42,350 | 8/3/2021 | 42,196 | Payment | 154 |
| 51 | 7/28/2021 | 81,458 | 7/15/2021 | 81,458 | Open | 81,458 |
| 52 | 7/30/2021 | 46,750 | 7/27/2021 | 46,750 | Open | 46,750 |
| 52 | 7/30/2021 | 46,750 | 8/24/2021 | 46,750 | Payment | - |
| 53 | 8/6/2021 | 45,100 | 8/2/2021 | 45,100 | Open | 45,100 |
| 55 | 8/11/2021 | 43,725 | 8/9/2021 | 43,725 | Open | 43,725 |
| 100 | 9/10/2020 | 250,000 | 9/10/2020 | 250,000 | Open | 250,000 |

A similar question was asked here [How to add next and subtract preceding row in SQL Server based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438741/how-to-add-next-and-subtract-preceding-row-in-sql-server-based-on-condition), but the main difference is i have to partition by ID and factor in the event date as well. That is why the solution there did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You should be able to use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when Event_Remark = 'Open' then Event_Amount
             when Event_Remark = 'Close' then 0
             else sum(case when Event_Remark = 'Open' then event_amount else 0) over (partition by id order by date_opened) +
                  sum(case when Event_Remark = 'Reversal' then event_amount else 0) over (partition by id order by date_opened) -
                  sum(case when Event_Remark = 'Payment' then event_amount else 0) over (partition by id order by date_opened)
        end) as closing_balance
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that there is at most one "Open" and "Close" per account and the "Open" is the first row and the "Close" the last row.

Comment: Can't you merge the conditions `case when Event_Remark in ('Open','Reversal','Reversal') then...`

Comment: @Charlieface . . . Yes, `'Open'` and `'Reversal'` could be combined.  However, this is how I think about the logic that the OP described.